# UTF-8 string displayed as backslash followed by numbers "\0646" in Delphi Berlin?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-10.1-berlin

Can some help me with the right way to correctly display UTF-8 unicode string ?

I am calling a procedure that receives a text string from web service. The procedure works fine a string is received perfectly. However, since the string contains an UTF-8 text, it displays unicode letters as numbers ...

```json
{"displayName":"\u062a\u0637\u0628\u064a\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0642 \u062f\u0639\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0627\u0621"
```

Delphi Berlin should support UTF-8 but I do not which function to use for encoding the UTF-8 and display the Text (Arabic Text) !!

```pascal
Procedure TF_Main.GnipHTTPSTransfer(Sender: TObject; Direction: Integer; BytesTransferred: Int64; PercentDone: Integer; Text: String);
Begin
  Inc(Transfer_Count);
  L_Counter.Caption:=IntToStr(Transfer_Count);
  write(GNIP_Text_File, Text);
  M_Memo.Lines.Add(text);
End;
```

Comment: I know very little about Delphi, but are you sure that code example is correct? Because it looks like it has syntax errors your example should be a [mcve].

Comment: Your code sample is invalid; it won't compile. That's also not a UTF-8 string - it's an encoded UTF-8 string. Berlin doesn't have any way to know that what you're adding to the memo is anything other than the exact value you're providing it. Why would you expect it to behave any differently than it is? You're telling it to put the string `'\u062a\u0637\u0628\u064a\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0642 \u062f\u0639\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0627\u0621'` into a memo control, and it's doing precisely what your code says to do.

Comment: Actually, it is an encoded Unicode string, no matter what specific encoding it comes from. `\uxxxx` can be decoded as UTF-8 as well as UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Answer (score 6):

The string is not UTF-8.  Even if it were transferred over HTTP using UTF-8, it is no longer UTF-8 in your `Text` string, it is UTF-16 instead.  Its content is a [JSON](http://json.org)-encoded object, which has a `displayName` field containing Unicode characters that are encoded using escape sequence notation (which is not strictly required in JSON, but is nonetheless supported).  Each `\uXXXX` is the escaped textual representation of a UTF-16 codeunit value (`\u062a` is Unicode codepoint `U+062A ARABIC LETTER TEH`, `\u0637` is `U+0637 ARABIC LETTER TAH`, etc).

Delphi has a [JSON framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Json), which will decode the escape sequences for you.  For example:

```
uses
  ..., System.JSON;

procedure TF_Main.GnipHTTPSTransfer(Sender: TObject; Direction: Integer; BytesTransferred: Int64; PercentDone: Integer; Text: String);
var
  JsonVal: TJSONValue;
  JsonObj: TJSONObject;
begin
  Inc(Transfer_Count);
  L_Counter.Caption := IntToStr(Transfer_Count);
  write(GNIP_Text_File, Text);
  M_Memo.Lines.Add(Text);

  JsonVal := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Text);
  if JsonVal <> nil then
  try
    JsonObj := JsonVal as TJSONObject;
    M_Memo.Lines.Add(JsonObj.Values['displayName'].Value); // تطبيـــق دعـــــاء
  finally
    JsonVal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did modify the code as suggested but ALWAYS getting an "Access violation at address 005F1060 in Module GNIP_Consumer.exe. Read of Address 00000008"

Comment: `ParseJSONValue()` returns a nil pointer if the parsing fails. I have updated my example to reflect that.

Comment: The modified code solved the problem and the Arabic text is shown for the  JSON value specified (displayname). However, My ultimate objective is to retrieve the WHOLE returned 'Text' in one variable/string in order to store in a text file for further processing. I am not sure if that can be done in Delphi ???

Comment: @Abdullah: Of course it can. You're putting it into a TMemo (with M_Memo.Lines.Add). Once you get it all in that memo, us M_Memo.Lines.SaveToFile to save the memo's content to whatever file you want.

Comment: you are right Ken, but that way I will have to parse all the JSON structure and extract every escape sequence individually using the Values['  '] index for each JSON pair. This is a length process !!. There must be a direct conversion that MAP a string that has escape sequence to its corresponding foreign language characters.

Comment: @AbdullahAldahlawi you need to parse the string. If you don't want to use the existing JSON parser, then parse the string yourself manually. JSON is a very simple format to parse, especially if you are only interested in escape sequences and nothing else. But really, what processing are you wanting to do that doesn't involve extracting strings from the JSON first?